# Get last entry in database

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'm new to Android and am trying to make an app that allows me to insert text and save it. 
Once it is saved to the database, when I click the button "Display" it will display that text I entered.

My problem is I don't know how to get the last entry in database.

Here is where I query the database:

```
public String getIDNotifPM() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_ROWIDPM, NOTIFPM};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(TABLE_NOTIFPM, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    c.moveToFirst();
    String notifIDPM = c.getString(0);
    return notifIDPM;
}
```

Here is my `OnClickListener`:

```
bViewNotifPM = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bViewNotifPM);
bViewNotifPM.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        try {
            DatabasePM w = new DatabasePM(this);
            w.open();
            String s = w.getIDNotifPM();
            w.close();
            long l = Long.parseLong(s);
            DatabasePM amem = new DatabasePM(this);
            amem.open();
            String returnedName = amem.getNotif(l);
            amem.close();

            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Notification!");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText("" + returnedName);
            d.setContentView(tv);
            d.show();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
cursor.moveToLast();
String notifIDPM = cursor.getString(0);
```